# Roll-up Summary of Multi-Currency field not accurate

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, roll-up-summary, multi-currency

We have a Roll-Up Summary Field on Opportunity called "Net Deposits" that sums up the Sales Price of the Opportunity Products.  We have enabled Multi-Currency for our org (Corporate Currency is USD).  Each Opportunity also has its own currency. For example, an Opportunity has two Opportunity Products each with a Sale Price CAD 10,000.00 (USD 7,888.71) and "Net Deposits" will display CAD 20,000.00 (USD 15,777.41)

We have a workflow that sends an email alert when "Net Deposits" is over a certain amount for different currencies.  This part is for CAD:

*AND(
Base_Currency__c = "CAD",
Net_CP_Deposits__c > 20000)*

Base_Currency__c is just a formula field TEXT(CurrencyIsoCode)

The issue is the alert is triggered when "Net Deposits" is EXACTLY CAD 20,000

I debug the workflow for this opportunity and one line shows this:

*Values:Net_CP_Deposits__c=20000.00000000000000000000000000000000000953080, Base_Currency__c=CAD*

I can't figure out why it has the lingering 953080 which causes it to be over 20,000. I recreated this workflow in a Flow and strangely it works as expected (does NOT trigger when it's 20,000). So I want to understand why the Roll-Up Summary field is not exactly 20,000 in a WF and why this is not an issue in a Flow?

Comment: Are Dated Exchange Rates enabled?

Comment: No it's not enabled

Comment: change your condition formula to `AND( Base_Currency__c = "CAD", ROUND(Net_CP_Deposits__c,0) > 20000)`; see [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000329918&type=1)

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to a known SalesForce issue from 6 days ago - currently in review [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000030w6QAA&title=roll-up-summary-field-shows-incorrect-value-from-child-records).

It may also be helpful to check out this article on SF fields [Behavior of decimal numbers when rounded off](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000332391&type=1). There's a chance the fields you're seeing as included in the rollup value are rounded in the layout view, but they may actually have more decimal places that are hidden but stored in the SF database, contributing to the trailing 953080.

There is also [an answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/328673/roll-up-summary-field-showing-wrong-value) that references setScale in SalesForce.